# UART communication between Rhino DC servo motor and RPi4 B

Tags: pi-4, serial, uart, dc-motor, gpiozero

I want to communicate with [this](https://rhinomc.com/products/integrated-dc-servo/high-torque-encoder-dc-servo-motor-10rpm-with-stepdir-drive/) **Rhino DC servo motor** with **RPi4 B**. I enable uart3 in RPi4 by modifying the */boot/config.txt* file. In this file, I add *dtoverlay=uart3* in the last. When I used `ls /dev/ttyAMA*` , I got */dev/ttyAMA0 /dev/ttyAMA1* , So I think uart3 is enable in RPi4.

For uart3, TXD is at GPIO04 and RXD is at GPIO05.  So, I connected RXD of RPi with TX of motor and vice-versa. In this servo motor, to rotate we have to give commands like *G200, G300,*, etc. To get the current position, we have to send *P*. This [link](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/12559/rotate-dc-servo-motor-with-arduino?rq=1) explains it in detail.

I used the below code to communicate with motor and RPi4:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA1', 
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=2
)

#ser.write(str.encode(str('G600')+'\n'))
ser.write('G600'.encode('utf-8'))
val = ser.read('P')
print(val)
ser.close()
```

But there was no rotation of the motor (no error was there too). and I got value `b' '` using `print(val)`

I want to know, how to run this servo motor with RPi4?

Comment: Use http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html to check for activity on GPIO4/5.    Check that the activity is as expected.  read('P') is wrong.  You need to write the command and then read the result.

Comment: Yes Sir, that what I'm asking. How to write the commands as my commands are like G200 etc.